# Autohotkey Most of numpad keys don't work

Tags: autohotkey

Here is my script. When I try it, only the NumpadClear (Num5) key works. I use Windows 7 64bit.

```
#SingleInstance force
#UseHook
#InstallKeybdHook
*~NumpadIns::MouseMove, 0, 1, 0, R 
*~NumpadClear::MouseMove, 0, -1, 0, R
*~NumpadEnd::MouseMove, -1, 0, 0, R
*~NumpadPgDn::MouseMove, 1, 0, 0, R
*~NumpadDown::Click
*~NumpadEnter::Click Right
```

Comment: Does it work with NumLock on? Off? Neither?

Comment: You either need to make sure your NumLock is off or use `SetNumLockState, Off`

Comment: Or, if it should work with both NumLock states, define hotkeys for both, e.g.: `Numpad0::` and `NumpadIns::`. The [key list](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm) specifies the respective equivalents. By the way, why do you use these modifiers `*~`? I don't see a reason why you would send a Numpad keystroke and then move the mouse cursor 1 pixel. Also, I don't see any key combination where it would make sense.

Answer (score 0):

This AutoHotkey script should achieve what you're looking for.
It will work whether NumLock is turned off or on.

```
#SingleInstance force
#UseHook
#InstallKeybdHook
NumpadIns::MouseMove, 0, 1, 0, R
NumpadClear::MouseMove, 0, -1, 0, R
NumpadEnd::MouseMove, -1, 0, 0, R
NumpadPgDn::MouseMove, 1, 0, 0, R
NumpadDown::Click
NumpadEnter::Click Right

Numpad0::MouseMove, 0, 1, 0, R
Numpad5::MouseMove, 0, -1, 0, R
Numpad1::MouseMove, -1, 0, 0, R
Numpad3::MouseMove, 1, 0, 0, R
Numpad2::Click
;NumpadEnter::Click Right
```

Comment: Also note these keys: NumpadIns, NumpadDiv, NumpadMult, NumpadAdd, NumpadSub, NumpadEnter. See https://autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm#Numpad_keys